# Celery/Django is running tasks every millisecond instead of on schedule when timezone has been set

Tags: django, celery

I am running into the issue that, when using a timezone inside my celery.py tasks run every chance it gets, thus running not according to schedule.

This is the output:

```
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,186: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,199: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,204: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,210: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,220: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,228: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,231: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,236: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,239: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,247: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
scheduler_1  | [2018-11-29 11:00:09,250: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Suppliers (biko.supplier.tasks.pull_supplier_data)
```

My celery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

# app = Celery('biko')

task_apps = [
  'biko.supplier.tasks',
  'biko.common.tasks',
  'biko.commerce.tasks',
  'biko.shop.tasks'
]

app = Celery('biko', include=task_apps)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Amsterdam'

app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.ONCE = {
  'backend': 'celery_once.backends.Redis',
  'settings': {
    'url': 'redis://' + os.getenv('REDIS_HOST'),
    'blocking': True,
    'default_timeout': 60 * 60,
    'blocking_timeout': 86400
  }
}
```

When I remove the app.config.timezone everything works fine.

My django settings regarding timezone...

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Any ideas what causes these issues?

Comment: There is a known issue with timezones in celery < v4.1.1.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @2ps Using 4.1.1

Comment: I would recommend trying this first with UTC.  If that works, you're options are to upgrade to celery 4.2.0 or to subclass `Celery` to add your own `now` function.

Comment: @2ps, updating to 4.2.0 did resolve this particular issue.